# What's the meaning of “astrung”?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *astrung*? I’ve read it from this passage from *Of Human Bondage*:

> She was terrified. She wanted him to reassure her; She looked at him pleadingly, not daring to ask for words of comfort but with all her nerves **astrung** to receive them: he had none to offer her.

In the dictionary I have there is no word such as *astrung*. What does this word mean?

Actually, I am afraid it’s just misprinted.

Comment: The _a-_ is an intensifying prefix; it just means ‘strung’.

Comment: Words created through basic derivational morphology need not be listed in the dictionary, and often are not.  You need to pick it apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the metadictionary at OneLook.com, but the word doesn't appear there at all. This suggests that it is either a nonce word, or (as you suggest) a misprint.

Because I found quite a few hits of 'astrung' in different online versions of Somerset Maugham's novel, which tends to discount the misprint theory, I'm guessing that Maugham added to *strung* the intensifying *a-* prefix that Janus Bahs Jacquet mentioned, in order to play on the idioms *living on one's nerves* and *highly strung*.

Comment: [See here](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22astrung%22&btnG=Search&num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=opera&hs=ZpQ&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks) for more. JBJ is surely correct.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a typo. It was written in 1915, so the language would be a bit different.

*Stringed instruments* need tightened *strings* (the tightly stretched cord or wire that produces a tone when caused to vibrate) to make a sound. To *string* them means to fit (new) strings to them and tighten them. The same is true of tennis racquets, bows, etc.

[*String*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/string) also means "to cause to be tense or nervous".

Finally, that sentence is followed by

> "I'm afraid you're very ill indeed," he said. "What d'you think it is?"

and later,

> "I know I've treated you shocking, but don't go..."

I think that this might be an attempt to imitate dialogue. Astrung sounds like that to my ear.

Answer (score 2):

William Somerset Maugham used the word in his THE LAND OF
THE BLESSED VIRGIN SKETCHES AND IMPRESSIONS IN ANDALUSIA published in 1905:

> It is very curious to wait in the darkness, in the silence, under the
>   myriad stars of the southern night. Your ear is astrung to hear the
>   distant tramp; the waiting seems endless.

Comment: -1  How does this *answer* the question as to the meaning of "astrung"?

Comment: If you read the comments above you will notice that the word is not found in any dictionary, and only literature.  Oddly, I found it in governmental crop report but this answers the indirect question or statement: "Actually, I am afraid it’s just misprinted."

Comment: I had read the comments, but your post needs to *answer* the question, What's the meaning of “astrung”?  You should have posted your findings as a comment, to reassure the OP it was not a misprint. You have the necessary rep to do so. Just edit your answer to include the definition and I reverse my downvote, if it bothers you.